Python scipy quad and nqaud giving different answers
I am not sure if this is more suitable for math stackexchange or stack overflow, but since the mathematical proofs look alright to me, I suspect its the code that's the issue and hence I will post it here:

The first formula (formula 1) is straight by definition:

and here's my code for formula 1:
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.integrate import nquad
from scipy.stats import norm
import math

def normalcdf(x):
    return (1+math.erf(x/math.sqrt(2)))/2

def normalpdf(x): 
    return math.exp(-x*x/2)/math.sqrt(2*math.pi)

def integrand12345(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,theta1,theta2,theta3,theta4,theta5):
  return normalpdf(x1 - theta1) * normalpdf(x2 - theta2) * normalpdf(x3 - theta3) * normalpdf(x4 - theta4) * normalpdf(x5 - theta5)

def range_x1(theta1,theta2,theta3,theta4,theta5):
  return [-np.inf, np.inf]

def range_x2(x1,theta1,theta2,theta3,theta4,theta5):
  return [x1, np.inf]

def range_x3(x2,x1,theta1,theta2,theta3,theta4,theta5):
  return [x2, np.inf] 

def range_x4(x3,x2,x1,theta1,theta2,theta3,theta4,theta5):
  return [x3, np.inf] 

def range_x5(x4,x3,x2,x1,theta1,theta2,theta3,theta4,theta5):
  return [x4, np.inf]

def pi_12345(theta1,theta2,theta3,theta4,theta5):
  return (nquad(integrand12345, [range_x5, range_x4, range_x3, range_x2, range_x1], args=(theta1,theta2,theta3,theta4,theta5)))[0]

The second formula (formula 2) is using double integration:

and here is the code for formula 2:
def integrandforpi_12(x1, x2, t1, t2, *theta): 
  prod = 1
  for ti in theta:
    prod = prod * (1 - normalcdf(x2 - ti))
  return prod * normalpdf(x1 - t1) * normalpdf(x2 - t2)

def range_x1(t1, t2, *theta):
  return [-np.inf, np.inf]

def range_x2(x1, t1, t2, *theta):
  return [x1, np.inf]

def pi_12(t1, t2, *theta):
  return (nquad(integrandforpi_12, [range_x2, range_x1], args=(t1, t2, *theta)))[0]

My third formula (formula 3) is based on Bayes' theorem:

and my code for formula 3 is:
def integrandforpi_i(xi, ti, *theta):
  prod = 1
  for t in theta:
    prod = prod * (1 - normalcdf(xi - t))
  return prod * normalpdf(xi - ti)

def pi_i(ti, *theta):
  return integrate.quad(integrandforpi_i, -np.inf, np.inf, args=(ti, *theta))[0]

So pi_i computes the probability that X_i is the smallest among the theta_i’s.
However, when I run my code using the 3 different formulas, they all give different answers and I have no idea why. I am not sure if there is a flaw in my derivation of the formula or if there's a mistake in my code. Any help would be appreciated.
Here is an example:
t1,t2,t3,t4,t5 = 0.83720022,0.61704171,1.21121701,0,1.52334078

p12345 = pi_12345(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5)
p12354 = pi_12345(t1,t2,t3,t5,t4)
p12435 = pi_12345(t1,t2,t4,t3,t5)
p12453 = pi_12345(t1,t2,t4,t5,t3)
p12534 = pi_12345(t1,t2,t5,t3,t4)
p12543 = pi_12345(t1,t2,t5,t4,t3)

print('p12345=',p12345)
print('p12354=',p12354)
print('p12435=',p12435)
print('p12453=',p12453)
print('p12534=',p12534)
print('p12543=',p12543)

print('formula 1 gives', p12345+p12354+p12435+p12453+p12534+p12543)

print('formula 2 gives', pi_12(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5))

print('formula 3 gives', pi_i(t2,t3,t4,t5) * pi_i(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5))

and the output is
p12345= 0.0027679276698449086
p12354= 0.008209750140618218
p12435= 0.0016182955786153714
p12453= 0.001921206801273682
p12534= 0.009675713474375739
p12543= 0.003904872716765966
formula 1 gives 0.028097766381493885
formula 2 gives 0.21897431741874426
formula 3 gives 0.0418669679120933

Remark: Formula 1 is extremely slow, it takes about 3 hours to run on my poor old laptop. Formula 2 and 3 are instant.

@StasSimonov Hi that’s a typo, it should be pi_i, computing the product of probability of X_1 that is smallest among X_1,…,X_5 and the probability of X_2 is the smallest among X_2,…,X_5. I edited the post and corrected the typo, thank you.

When i run your code with the ti you've provided, I don't get the same outputs that you do. Please try re-running your code.

@MattHaberland Hi it seems I have input the wrong numbers in the example. I just rerun it again and edited the question. It should now be error free. Thank you so much.

Since the nquad ranges list is reversed, the integrand X argument list should be reversed too:
def integrand12345(x5,x4,x3,x2,x1,theta1,theta2,theta3,theta4,theta5):

and
def integrandforpi_12(x2, x1, t1, t2, *theta):

Then my results become:
formula 1 gives 0.04444581969881939
formula 2 gives 0.04444465903549115
formula 3 gives 0.0418669679120933

Also I significantly decreased the calculation time of formula 1 passing the opts argument to nquad: opts={'epsabs':0.001}

1 & 2 looks right - they agree with simulation.

@Stas Simonov, thank you so much for your help! Does that mean formula 3 is wrong? the number is reasonably close but not as close as formula 1 and 2 are. Although I can't see anything wrong with formula 3, mathematically or the code.

@Ishigami, I think, it's a loss of precision. But I don't know where.

@Stat Simonov Thank you so much for your help!

This doesn't fully answer the question, but it might be helpful to know if any of these are correct. For that, we have simulation:
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
rng = np.random.default_rng(43258234589253)

ti = np.asarray([0.83720022, 0.61704171, 1.21121701, 0, 1.52334078])

n_trials = 1000000
n_obs = len(ti)
desired_ranks = np.arange(1, n_obs+1)

Xi = rng.standard_normal(size=(n_trials, n_obs)) + ti
ranks = stats.rankdata(Xi, axis=1)
in_order = np.all(ranks[:, :2] == desired_ranks[:2], axis=1)
p = np.mean(in_order)
print(p)  # 0.044489

If this code is correct (and please correct me if I've misunderstood and I'll correct this), then none of the integrals are right.

Actually, I also simulated P(x1 is smallest of all xi) * P(x2 is smallest of x2, x3, x4, x5). It gives the same result as integral 3, but not the same as the full simulation or integrals 1/2 (after correction). In your derivation, you are treating P(x2 is second smallest | x1 is smallest) as equivalent to P(x2 is smallest of x2, x3, x4, x5). That part may not be right, because it ignores the fact that x2 > x1.

Thank you so much for your help. I don't see any errors in your code either. And the answer of my formula 3 seems reasonable close to your simulation. But then I would like to ask why formula 1,2 are wrong (and is formula 3 really correct for that matter)
